# how to convert the stdobject array into normal array

Tags: php, json, stdclass

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [card] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Abc
                    [number] => 1234567123456798
                    [exp_month] => 1
                    [exp_year] => 2015
                    [cvc] => 123
                )

            [deliveryPeriod] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [store_id] => 1
                    [start_date] => 2014-11-01
                    [end_date] => 2014-12-31
                    [delivery_schedules] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [delivery_period_id] => 1
                                    [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                    [end_time] => 18:00:00
                                    [slot_capacity] => 25
                                    [delivery_fee] => 2
                                    [used_capacity] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

                )

        )

)
```

I have this stdclass object array and i want to convert this to a normal array.I was using foreach but i can loop through inner array.how can i do that in php.please help me i am new to php.

Comment: What is a "normal array"? What have you tried so far? Please add your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use
[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Where `$object` is your multi-dimensional nested object.

**Explanation:**

First JSON encode your object, then JSON decode it.

With second argument `associative` to `TRUE`.

This way, you will get an associative array without caring of nested depth.

Answer (score 2):

Create a recursive function

```
function objectToArray($obj, &$new_array){
    foreach($obj as $key => $value){
       if(is_object($value){
          $new_array[$key] = array();
          objectToArray($value, $new_array[$key]);
       } else {
          $new_array[$key] = $value;
       }

       return $new_array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use typecasting by using `(array)` in front of the array in question... So for you:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    $itemArray = (array)$item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could typecast your array like the example below:

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->test = 'Hello';
var_dump($obj);

$arr = (array)$obj;
var_dump($arr);
```

Returns:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
}
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
}
```